# Why I cannot save an Account?

Tags: lightning

Why I cannot save an Account? What's wrong with my code?

//This is my component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="AccountController">
    <ui:inputText aura:id="AccName"  class="slds-input"   updateOn="keyup"/><br/>
    <ui:inputText aura:id="AccountNumber"  class="slds-input"   updateOn="keyup"/><br/>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.insertNewAccount}">Save</button> 
</aura:component>
```

//This is my controller

```
insertNewAccount : function(component, event, helper){
    var inputtedAccName = component.find("AccName");
    var inputtedAccountNumber = component.find("AccountNumber");

    var valueAccName = inputtedAccName.get("v.value");
    var valueAccountNumber = inputtedAccountNumber.get("v.value");
    //alert(valueAccName+ " , "+ valueAccountNumber) ;

    var action = component.get("c.saveAccount");

    action.setParams({
        "Name" : valueAccName,
        "AccountName" : valueAccountNumber
    });

    action.setCallBack(this, function(a){
        var state = a.getState();
        if(state === "SUCCESS"){
            var name = a.getReturnValue();
            alert("Account name " + name + " successfully saved.");
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

//This is my apex class

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account saveAccount(Account acc){

        upsert acc;
        return acc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `saveAccount` in `AccountController` takes only one parameter 'Account acc'.

```
public static Account saveAccount(Account acc){
```

In the Lightning controller, you are passing 2 parameters to it:

```
var action = component.get("c.saveAccount");

action.setParams({
    "Name" : valueAccName,
    "AccountName" : valueAccountNumber
});
```

Modify the above so that it takes an Account instance.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem in your code.

You are passing 2 parameter in action set.params but in sever side you are receiving only one value.

for example:

```
 action.setParams({
    "Name" : valueAccName,
    "AccountName" : valueAccountNumber
});
```

It should be like this:

```
 @AuraEnabled
  public static Account saveAccount(string Name,string AccountName ){
  account ac=new account();
   ac.Name=Name;
    ac.AccountName__c=AccountName;
     insert ac;
   return ac; }
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. But still cannot save.

Comment: public with sharing class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account saveAccount(string Name,string AccountNumber ){
        account ac=new account();
        ac.Name=Name;
        ac.AccountNumber=AccountNumber;
        insert ac;
        return ac;
    }  
}

Comment: whats the value you are getting in ac; please put one system.debug just show me ac value

Comment: Also put console.log for below  code:  var valueAccName = inputtedAccName.get("v.value");
    var valueAccountNumber = inputtedAccountNumber.get("v.value");  and also check "other required fields" in account level  &CHECK your debug log  show me the error message

Comment: Thanks @Annappa PH, there is no error now. It's in my org that has something wrong. I edited the code a little bit , I changed ac.AccountName to ac.AccountNumber. Now my codes worked well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if it resolves  your query  and  make it as best answer and please close the question